# Clipboard manager for pasting multiple items at once?

Tags: macos, copy-paste

I'm looking for an app that let me copy multiple items from different locations and paste them at once, I have tried many clipboard managers but none of them let me to paste my whole clipboard history at once and I have to paste the items one by one which is not good at all.

Please help me if there is a clipboard manager or app (for Lion) that let me do that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My favourite swiss army knife for OS X, [LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html), has clipboard history and management. In addition to being able to access historical, clipped information it can also do clip-merge. A quick double press of Cmd-C will merge the currently selected contents in to the current top-of-the-heap clipboard object for you, allowing you to paste them as one object with a single Cmd-V.

You can merge multiple items in the clipboard history by selecting the first one and doing Cmd-C and then selecting additional items and doing the quick, double press of Cmd-C. They'll all get merged in to the top item as expected.

Comment: The price of that tool for this functionality is too much. (and I am not interested in other features). It is very interesting why such a feature is not needed for mac users.